# Use Embedded Assembly when there is already another version of the same Assembly loaded?

Tags: c#, plugins, version, .net-assembly

I have the following situation:

In my workplace, I am developing a plugin based Desktop Application.
The goal is that the plugins are completely independet in their functionality spectrum from the Core Application.

Now I have the situation that the Core references Version 1.0.0.4 of a library, but a plugin references version 1.0.0.8 of the same library.

The plugin and all needed references are merged into a single .dll file using Fody.Costura.
When running my Application, i get a **"System.MissingMethodException"**,
because the plugin calls a method of the aforementioned library, that is not yet present in the version the core uses.

**How can I explicitely tell the plugin to load and use the assembly version that is embedded in the plugin itself?**

I can't seem to find a way to accomplish this, i have already tried using Binding Redirect to the newer version, or loading the assembly manually in code, but it just won´t work...

Comment: Why don't update core application to use v1.0.0.8? There are a couple of options, but it won't be easy to implement.

Comment: Sure I could (and will) update the core to use v1.0.0.8, but the ultimate goal is that once the core is deployed to one of our customers, it should not have to be touched again when deploying new "Plug-ins". There will always be the probability that one of our libraries gets updated or extended, and i want to be sure that the plugin contains all the libraries it needs to run, even on older versions of the core.

Comment: I see your point. Since this is desktop app (assuming full .NET, not Core one), you can use app domains to isolate plugins inside sandbox.

Comment: I tried using seperate AppDomains to load the other version of the assembly, but  sadly found no success with this approach either. I have to add that my knowledge and experience in this territory (AppDomains, Sandbox, etc..) is limited, as i havent had to work with it before...